# Itunes archive upload issue ITMS-90530 and ITMS 90098

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am having the following issue when i start uploading the app. i have added `armv7, arm64` to `Required device capabilities`  but still its giving issue. Here are the errors:

[image]

Comment: its not the solution. i have already added that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the steps i did for my problem. Problem solved.
before you archive the app do the following steps,

1. Un-plug the device from mac.
2. Clean and build the project.
3. Archive the project.
4. Validate.
5. Upload.

Comment: I am happy , it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution:*

Change the device to `Generic iOS Device` or unplug your 64bit phone

.

*Reason:*

Check **Build Active Architecture Only** in `Build Settings > Architectures`

if **YES**, xcode will determine the architecture of the test device selected and it will build for that only.

if **NO**, xcode will build for all architectures considering your minimumOSVersion

NOTE: setting `Build Active Architecture` to `YES` is faster when building, so use it when you need it fast

Answer (score -1):

Those keys don't work the way you think they do : it's an AND not an OR. By including the arm64 key you are saying your app is for 64-bit devices only, which is not allowed on iOS 8. Delete the arm64 key.

Apple said at WWDC that 64-bit-only iOS apps will be allowed on iOS 9, but you'd need to be building with XCode 7 and targeting iOS 9.

You can also give those keys true and false values, which makes things more complicated. See Apple's docs if you want to know more. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1397/_index.html

Comment: Delete require device capability and try again.Make Archietectures in build setting to standard and for valid arc add arm64.arm7,arm7s.Set build active arc : debug to YES and release to NO.Create archive again